# merging convex hulls in java

Tags: java, merge, convex-hull

I've written a java program which which uses the divide and conquer algorithm to find the convex hull of a polygon in a cartesian coordination.
I have a class Coord which has two "double" fields X and y and "this" which I'm using the method on, is a collection of coordinates (set). 
my method should return the hull (Collection) of the polygon

My code is like this:

```
    public Collection<Coord> territoire()
    {
        Collection<Coord> sommets = new ArrayList<Coord>();
        ArrayList<Coord> thisToArrList = new ArrayList<Coord>();
        for(Coord c : this)
            thisToArrList.add(c);

        ArrayList<Coord> sortedPointsByX = new ArrayList<Coord>(); 


        int n = this.size();
        if (n <= 2)
            return this;

        //sorting the points by their X coordinates 
        sortedPointsByX = sortedArrayByX(thisToArrList);

        //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> works good till here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        // now sortedPointsByX array contains the points with increasing X 
        // splitting the sortedPointsByX into two arrays  
        ArrayList<Coord> firstPart = new ArrayList<Coord>();
        ArrayList<Coord> secondPart = new ArrayList<Coord>();

        // if the number of the points is prime, the leftmost and the rightmost half
        // both have same number of points
        if(sortedPointsByX.size() % 2 == 0)
        {   

            for(int i = 0; i < sortedPointsByX.size()/2; i++)
            {
                firstPart.add(sortedPointsByX.get(i));

            }

            for(int i = sortedPointsByX.size()/2; i < sortedPointsByX.size(); i++)
            {
                secondPart.add(sortedPointsByX.get(i));
            }

        }
        //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>works good till here<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


        // if the number of points is odd, the leftmost half have the extra points 
        else 
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < sortedPointsByX.size()/2+1; i++)
            {
                firstPart.add(sortedPointsByX.get(i));
            }

            for(int i = sortedPointsByX.size()/2+1; i < sortedPointsByX.size(); i++)
            {
                secondPart.add(sortedPointsByX.get(i));
            }
        }

        //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>works good till here<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

        CoordSet firstSet = new CoordSet(firstPart);
        CoordSet secondSet = new CoordSet(secondPart);


        // converting the arrays to list of coordinates in order to use recursion over them 


        //recursion for sub coordsets
        Collection<Coord> firstSetSommet = firstSet.territoire();
        Collection<Coord> secondSetSommet = secondSet.territoire();

        ArrayList<Coord> firstHull = new ArrayList<Coord>(firstSetSommet);
        ArrayList<Coord> secondHull = new ArrayList<Coord>(secondSetSommet);

        sommets = mergeHulls(firstHull, secondHull);


        return sommets;
    }


    public Collection<Coord> mergeHulls(ArrayList<Coord> firstHull, ArrayList<Coord> secondHull) 
    {

        Collection<Coord> pointsInside = new ArrayList<Coord>();
        Collection<Coord> sommets = new ArrayList<Coord>();

      //********************upper tangent***************       

        //find the highest point of the leftmost part
        Coord firstPartHighestPoint = getMaxY(firstHull);
        //find the highest point of the rightmost part 
        Coord secondPartHighestPoint = getMaxY(secondHull);

        for(int i = 0; i< firstHull.size(); i++)
        {
            // check if the points lie on the line between highest point in leftmost and in rightmost
            // if true, the current point is above the line
            if(isCollinear(firstPartHighestPoint, secondPartHighestPoint, firstHull.get(i))>0)
            {
                // the current point is above the line
                firstPartHighestPoint = firstHull.get(i);
            }
            pointsInside.add(firstPartHighestPoint);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < secondHull.size(); i++)
        {
            if(isCollinear(firstPartHighestPoint, secondPartHighestPoint, secondHull.get(i))>0)
            {
                // the current point is above the line
                secondPartHighestPoint = secondHull.get(i);
            }
            pointsInside.add(secondPartHighestPoint);

        }

        //******************lower tangent***************     

        //find the lowest point of the leftmost part 
        Coord firstPartLowestPoint = getMinY(firstHull);
        // find the lowest point of the rightmost part
        Coord secondPartLowestPoint = getMinY(secondHull);

        for(int i = 0; i< firstHull.size(); i++)
        {
            // check if the points lie on the line between highest point in leftmost and in rightmost
            // if true, the current point is above the line
            if(isCollinear(firstPartLowestPoint, secondPartLowestPoint, firstHull.get(i)) < 0)
            {
                // the current point is above the line
                firstPartLowestPoint = firstHull.get(i);
            }
            pointsInside.add(firstPartLowestPoint);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < secondHull.size(); i++)
        {
            if(isCollinear(firstPartLowestPoint, secondPartLowestPoint, secondHull.get(i)) < 0)
            {
                // the current point is above the line
                secondPartLowestPoint = secondHull.get(i);
            }
            pointsInside.add(firstPartLowestPoint);
        }

        sommets.addAll(firstHull);
        sommets.addAll(secondHull);
        sommets.removeAll(pointsInside);

        return sommets;
    }     

//**********************************Auxiliary méthods****************************************************

    // if the equation is equal to 0, the points are collinear
    // the method returns the determinant of the point matrix
    // This determinant tells how far point 'c' is from vector ab and on which side
    // it is 
    // < 0 if the point 'c' is below the line (assumption : horizontal line) 
    // > 0 if the point 'c' is above the line 
    public double isCollinear(Coord a, Coord b, Coord c)
    {
         return ((b.x - a.x)*(c.y - a.y) - (b.y - a.y)*(c.x - a.x));
    }



//************************************** line equation ************************************************ 

    // find the slope of the line between two points
    public static double findSlope(Coord point1, Coord point2)
    {
        return (point2.y - point1.y)/(point2.x-point1.x);
    }

    // finding the constant 'b' of the line equation y = xm + b 
    public static double constantB(Double slope, Coord point)
    {
        return point.y - slope* point.x;

    }

//*************************************** Minimum and Maximum "Y" *****************************************

    // the point with maximum Y
    public static Coord getMaxY(ArrayList<Coord> points) 
    {
        double maxY = points.get(0).y;   // start with the first value
        Coord maxPoint = points.get(0);
        for (int i=1; i<points.size(); i++) {
            if (points.get(i).y > maxY) 
            {
                maxY = points.get(i).y; // new maximum
                maxPoint = points.get(i);
            }
        }
        return maxPoint;
    }

    // a method to find the Point with the minimum y 
    public static Coord getMinY(ArrayList<Coord> points)
    {  
          double minValue = points.get(0).y;
          Coord minPoint = points.get(0);
          for(int i=1;i<points.size();i++){  
            if(points.get(i).y < minValue)
            {
                minPoint = points.get(i);
                minValue = points.get(i).y;  
            }  
          }  
          return minPoint;  
    } 

//************************************** sorting the points ******************************************** 

    //sorting the points by their x in ascending order
    public static ArrayList<Coord> sortedArrayByX(ArrayList<Coord> arrayOfPoints)
    {
        //double minval = arrayOfPoints[0].x;
        Coord temp = null;
        for(int i = 0; i< arrayOfPoints.size(); i++)
        { 
            for(int j = 0; j< arrayOfPoints.size()-1; j++)
            {
                if(arrayOfPoints.get(j+1).x < arrayOfPoints.get(j).x)
                {
                    temp = arrayOfPoints.get(j+1);
                    arrayOfPoints.set(j+1, arrayOfPoints.get(j));
                    arrayOfPoints.set(j, temp);  
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayOfPoints;
    }
```

I can't get why when I run the program, the following message shows up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at miniprojet2.CoordSet.getMaxY(CoordSet.java:270)
    at miniprojet2.CoordSet.mergeHulls(CoordSet.java:154)
    at miniprojet2.CoordSet.territoire(CoordSet.java:139)
    at miniprojet2.CalculeTerritoire.main(CalculeTerritoire.java:36)
```

I'll be so glad if you tell me where I've made a mistake

Comment: That's a runtime error, not a compile-time error.

Comment: yes, you are right. my bad :) but I don't even know why I got this error

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: *I'm assuming your code fails at `firstPart.add(sortedPointsByX.get(i))`. If you post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), I could provide better assistance.*

`sortedPointsByX` has zero size.

Your code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sortedPointsByX.size()/2+1; i++) {
    firstPart.add(sortedPointsByX.get(i));
}
```

thus evaluates to:

```
for (int i=0; i<(0 / 2) + 1; i++) {
    firstPart.add(sortedPointsByX.get(i));
}
```

which is:

```
for (int i=0; i<1; i++) {
    firstPart.add(sortedPointsByX.get(i));
}
```

which is, in turn, equivalent to:

```
firstPart.add(sortedPointsByX.get(0));
```

However, you can't get the zeroeth element of `sortedPointsByX` because it is empty.

---

You can tell all this from your error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
```

An `IndexOutOfBoundsException` means you tried to access some index `i` such that `i < 0` or `i >= size()`. The error reports that the size is zero and that you tried to access index 0; thus, `0 ≥ 0` and your code fails.

Comment: but I've tested (with System.out.println()) the parts which I wrote under "works good till here" and so I printed the elements of the sortedPointsByX and it had elements inside (correct elements).

Comment: I'm testing this set of numbers:
0 0, 
0 3.75,
1 2.5,
1 0.5,
1.5 1.5,
-4 1.5,
-3 1.3,
-2 1.1,
-1 0.9,
0 0.7,
-2.9 1.5,
-1.8 1.5,
-0.7 1.5,
0.6 1.5,
-3 1.7,
-2 1.9,
-1 2.1,
0 2.3,
-3.2 1.2,
-2.4 0.9,
-1.6 0.6,
-0.8 0.3,
-3.2 1.95,
-2.4 2.4,
-1.6 2.85,
-0.8 3.3,